# Problem with Outlook macro - sometimes attachment is not added

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created a macro that attaches selected email to the message and sends it to the pre-populated address.

However sometimes macro stops attaching selected email.

Can anyone advise what may be the reason? Here is my code.

```
Sub ForwardOutsource()

On Error Resume Next

Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
   MsgBox ("No item selected")
   Exit Sub
End If

For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With objMsg
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "info@info.com"
        .Attachments.Add objItem, olEmbeddeditem
        .Subject = objItem.Subject
        .To = "address@address.com"
        .Display
        End With
Next

Set objItem = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry for not replying earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Well you should remove [On Error Resume Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement) from your code, you are basically telling the code  to continue to next line if an error occurred.*

*by the way you are not using it correctly as well*

*Here is good link http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm*

*Next try using [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) and Declare variables*

*clean up your code example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Fw_Items_As_Atmt()
    '//  Declare variables
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem

'    Select msg
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No Item selected")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set msg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    For Each Item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

        With msg
            .Attachments.Add Item, olEmbeddeditem ' Attch Selected email
            .Subject = "See Attached Items"
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .HTMLBody = ""
            .Display
        '    .Send
        End With
    Next

    '// Clean up
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set msg = Nothing
End Sub
```